# Calabash Automation: Testing app with backend CRUD

Tags: automated-tests, calabash

Calabash is great for testing functionalities within the app. But I feel there is big limitation in my testing as my app requires quite a bit of backend and frontend changes.For example, I have an app that is for managing coupons. As business user, I can create new coupons on the backend which will update the database. This then is pushed to the app. During my manual testing, I am trying to see if all the functionalities are working after the new coupon is received. How can I automate the updating of the database?

I have webservice URLs for the various functions. Is it possible to get calabash to run the webservice URL to create, delete or update the coupons?

Comment: By webservice you mean some kind of APIs that can be accessed from the outside, right?

Answer (score 0):

In general, anything you can do with ruby, you can put into a step definition.

I have seen calabash test suites that do exactly what you describe.